# ng-cli/rxjs: multiple Observable modules?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to use a observable for the first time.  i'm using `angular-cli` to `build/serve` my project: when I serve my app I get the following error.  Any idea what this means? Why would there be two observable modules?  i'm using this to handle a rest response from a local server but it seems like I might be getting back the wrong observable as i'm getting a `NET_ERR` as response...

my error:

> lang.js:124Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call
>   enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>       client:38[WDS] Warnings while compiling.
>       client:73./~/rxjs/Observable.js
>       There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing.
>       This can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.
>       Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>       * C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\node_modules\rxjs\Observable.js
>           Used by 6 module(s), i. e.
>           C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\node_modules\@angular\core\src\facade\async.js
>       * C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\node_modules\rxjs\observable.js
>           Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>           C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\dist\entry.js?{"useForkChecker":true,"tsconfig":"C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\src\tsconfig.json","externals":["C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/app.component.spec.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/app.component.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/app.module.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/Components/product/product.component.spec.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/Components/product/product.component.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/index.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/models/product.model.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/services/rest.service.spec.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/app/services/rest.service.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/environments/environment.prod.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/environments/environment.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/main.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/polyfills.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/test.ts","C:/Users/Deon/Documents/trade-link/barcode-checker/src/typings.d.ts"],"doTypeCheck":true,"sourceMap":true,"verbose":false}!C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\node_modules\angular2-template-loader\index.js!C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\src\app\services\rest.service.tswarnings
>   @ client:73
>       error_handler.js:48EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:5:42 caused by: this.http.get(...).map
>   is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:48
>       error_handler.js:50ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: this.http.get(...).map is not a functionErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:50
>       error_handler.js:53ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:53
>       error_handler.js:54TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function
>           at RestService.getProduct (rest.service.ts:13)
>           at AppComponent.submitBarcode (app.component.ts:25)
>           at _View_AppComponent0._handle_click_9_0 (component.ngfactory.js:111)
>           at view.js:365
>           at dom_renderer.js:262
>           at dom_events.js:30
>           at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:232)
>           at Object.onInvoke (ng_zone.js:238)
>           at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:231)
>           at Zone.runGuarded (zone.js:128)ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:54
>       error_handler.js:57ERROR CONTEXT:ErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:57
>       error_handler.js:58DebugContextErrorHandler.handleError @ error_handler.js:58
>       zone.js:158Uncaught ViewWrappedError

RestService: (Which uses the observable)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions  } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from  "rxjs/observable";
import { ProductModel } from "../models/product.model";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw' 




@Injectable()
export class RestService {
public API_URL: string = "http://10.60.160.34/BRMServices/WebEnquiry/";
private headers: Headers;
private options: RequestOptions;


  constructor(private http: Http){
      this.init();
  }

  init() {
      this.headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
      this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }

  getProduct(barcode: string): Observable<ProductModel> {

      return this.http.get(this.API_URL + "/POSEnquiry/" + barcode, this.options)
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
  }  
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { RestService } from "./services/rest.service";
import { ProductModel } from "./models/product.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

    product: ProductModel;

    constructor(private restService: RestService){

    }

submitBarcode(barcode: HTMLInputElement){

    this.restService.getProduct(barcode.value)
    .subscribe(
    (res) => {
        //product = res;
        console.log(res);
    },
    (res) => {
        console.log("failure" + res);
    }
    );
    //console.log("product: " + product);
}

}
```

Comment: can you post AppComponent code

Comment: @anshuVersatile I added app.component and restService.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error occures because it cannot find map in the references.

> TypeError: this.http.get(...).map is not a function at
>   RestService.getProduct (rest.service.ts:13)

In this case I would suggest to use `import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx'` instead of `import { Observable } from  "rxjs/observable";` and all `import 'rxjs/add/...'`. this will remove the warning of two observable modules with different casing.

Could you also use RequestOptionsArgs instead of RequestOptions. I think this will resolve the error. (When I compare my code with yours these are the only difference)